# Mysql Sorting of dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

In DB there is a column for storing date which is in milliseconds.
I want to select the sorted milliseconds value from database. What will be the way out for this?

For instance,

Tablename : xyz,
Columnname : Time ( Datatype : varchar(45)).

The table is containig rows with values like 1390274501774,1390274536947,1390274570978, 1390274611391 and 1390274659078 etc. These values are in milliseconds which are getting stored.

I want to select the above value using php-mysql in "SORTED" manner.What will be the query?

How to achieve that in php-mysql?

Comment: What about `ORDER BY`? Sounds familiar?

Comment: The datatype of the field is varchar. Will it produce the right output for date? according to you what will be the query with a formatted date string output in sorted manner.

Comment: You can use datatype timestamp or datetime instead of varchar. It will be better for comparing dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Time,'%d/%m/%Y') FROM xyz ORDER BY Time ASC
```

(or DESC for descending order)

You can read more about how to format your date using the DATE_FORMAT() [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Time is varchar, if you have values like 99274659078, order will not be correct. And DATE_FORMAT will output null because Time is not date, it's milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

The Query should be :

```
Select `Time` FROM xyz ORDER BY FROM_UNIXTIME(`Time`/1000) ASC;
```

Comment: Lot of thanks for the response , but i need column with formatted date string in sorted manner. The values are stored in milliseconds.

Comment: The order by clause just needs the values to be numeric. ORDER BY FROM_UNIXTIME(time/1000) is about [68 times](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/29828) slower than just Time+0

Answer (score 0):

If you data is varchar format your ORDER BY clause will have to convert the type
and if you need the miliseconds shown as a date, convert them to seconds and use [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) . This function has a optional format parameter if you need it
in other format than the standard one.

You can do:

```
SELECT id, FROM_UNIXTIME(ROUND(Time/1000,0)) AS ooo FROM xyz ORDER BY Time+0
```

(play with it at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b71b/4)

ORDER BY expression, not index field, is very expensive, performance wise, you need to keep it as simple as possible.

You may consider not storing them as varchar but bigint and even adding another column, DATETIME, to
save the actual date.

It would help the question to add something like 99274659078 in the values list so
the problem of ORDER BY varchar is exemplified.

Comment: Thanks... what if i changed it to 'SELECT id, FROM_UNIXTIME(ROUND(Time/1000,0)) AS ooo FROM xyz ORDER BY Time' . Will this work ? if I change Time+0 to only time in order by clause.

Comment: You may get the expected result but understand this: The string "99" is greater than the string "100", while the number 99 is not greater than the number 100. Your Time column is string (varchar). Your values (1,390,274,501,774) have 13 digits. When/If you will have 12 digits or 14 digits values your order (without+0) will fail.

Comment: Okie..got it. Will the same query be used in PHP mysqlquery?

Comment: yes, use [mysqli_query](http://www.php.net/mysqli_query) << there are some usefull examples there